# ERROR: While running simple count(*) using hive2

Tags: hive, beeline, tez

I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.waitForOperationToComplete(HiveStatement.java:349)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.execute(HiveStatement.java:251)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.executeQuery(HiveStatement.java:434)
    at Hive.main(Hive.java:21)
```

I have added `hive-serde-2.1.1.jar` from intellij. If I run `select * from <table>` it gives me result , but if I run `select count(*) from <table>` I get above error. Can anyone help me with this ?

**UPDATE :** I get this stack trace from yarn-gui

```
Application application_1499656878152_0003 failed 2 times due to Error launching appattempt_1499656878152_0003_000002. Got exception: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.InvalidAuxServiceException: The auxService:mapreduce_shuffle does not exist
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.impl.pb.SerializedExceptionPBImpl.instantiateExceptionImpl(SerializedExceptionPBImpl.java:171)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.impl.pb.SerializedExceptionPBImpl.instantiateException(SerializedExceptionPBImpl.java:182)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.impl.pb.SerializedExceptionPBImpl.deSerialize(SerializedExceptionPBImpl.java:106)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.amlauncher.AMLauncher.launch(AMLauncher.java:123)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.amlauncher.AMLauncher.run(AMLauncher.java:250)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
. Failing the application.
```

Comment: You should check hive log `/tmp/${user.name}/hive.log` after triggering this query and paste here if you are not able to get useful info. Thanks!

Comment: @Prem hive.log has all 
`0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000`